# How to search a set of data using a key in a file with C programming

Tags: c

I have a file which has Item details, like barcode, price, quantity... The number of items may vary in range of thousands or ten thousands... I need to get complete data of an item when i search with a detail. (say, i use barcode always to search item). Can anyone suggest a best way to implement this in C?

Comment: hashmap if you use barcode always. If you search within let's say description a dictionary might be the solution

Comment: @bolov: i use barcode always.. if so which is the best technique.. can you name some..?

Comment: in that case, as I said: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: Why not use long-existing utilities such as `grep` or `awk`?